# Enter button doesn't trigger

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i am trying to open a google search window using python and the enter button trigger doesn't work.
so if you press the enter button it should open the window but it doesn't.
i am also using tkinter for gui.
help me :( thanks
(i am using win 10)

```
import tkinter as tk


def keyup():
    opener()

def opener():

    import webbrowser
    text = name.get().strip()
    query=str(text)
    webbrowser.open("www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_koUS766US766&ei=rDxSWtPFOeKt0gK4_YioDg&q="+query)
def clear():
    name.delete(0, 'end')
    root = tk.Tk()
    ler=tk.Label(root, text = "what do you want to search?",font=("Helvetica", 40))
    ler.pack()


name = tk.Entry(root,width=100)
name.pack()

widget=tk.Button(root, text = 'search', command =opener,width=30,height=3)
widget.pack()
widget.bind('<Enter>', opener)
wider=tk.Button(root, text = 'clear', command =clear,width=10,height=3)
wider.pack()




root.mainloop()
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: You have wrong indentions in code - so we can't test it

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? Always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: `<Enter>` means `mouse hover widget`, not key "Enter" on keyboard. For key "Enter" there is `<Return>`.

Comment: `command=` executes function without argument but `bind()` executes with one argument - so `opener` has to get one argument with default value to works with both - ie. `def opener(event=None):`

Answer (score 1):

You have few mistakes

1. for key `"Enter"` is event `<Return>`. You can also assign `<Return>` to `root` and it works even when button is not selected/focused.

   ```
   root.bind('<Return>', opener)
   ```

   or assign to `Entry`

   ```
   name.bind('<Return>', opener)
   ```

   and `"Enter"` will run `opener` only when `Entry` is focused.
2. `command=` executes function without arguments but `bind()` executes function with one argument so you have to define function with argument which has default value and then it will work with both.

   ```
   def opener(event=None):
   ```
3. use `http://` in url because you can use `file://` to open local file. On Linux link without `http://` is treated as local file.

Smaller mistakes: put all `import` at top to make code more readable, `Entry` returns string so you don't need `str()`

---

**EDIT:** added `name.bind('<Return>', opener)`

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

def opener(event=None):
    text = name.get().strip()
    webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+text)

def clear():
    name.delete(0, 'end')

root = tk.Tk()

ler=tk.Label(root, text="what do you want to search?", font=("Helvetica", 40))
ler.pack()

name = tk.Entry(root,width=100)
name.pack()
name.bind('<Return>', opener) # added 

widget=tk.Button(root, text='search', command=opener, width=30, height=3)
widget.pack()
widget.bind('<Return>', opener)

wider = tk.Button(root, text='clear', command=clear, width=10, height=3)
wider.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @iwasnothere text "doesn't work" is useless information (and the most annoing text on StackOverflow) If it doesn't work then describe what exactly doesn't work, what did you expect, maybe you expect something diffferent then you described in question. Currently key `Enter` works when you select button "search" - as in your original code. If you need working `Enter` when you still in `Entry` then you have to bind to `Entry` - `name.bind('<Return>', opener)`  - see new code.

Answer (score 0):

With Tk, the event binding `<Enter` is used to describe the cursor moving over the space occupied by the widget (entering the space). The binding you wish to use is `<Return>`, which is mapped to the return (enter) key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `<Return>` instead of `<Enter>`. Also, the indentations seem incorrect.